# Newtonsoft JsonConvert.DefaultSettings strange behavior

Tags: c#, json.net

I've faced with strange behavior(at least for me) of `JsonConvert.DefaultSettings`
In my apps i define default json settings for whole app, but in case if i need exclusive serialization of some object i thought that i can pass `JsonSerializerSettings` as second argument to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` and that settings will override the default one.
but it seems that this is not correct.

I found that settings passed as second argument are ignored.
so, if i need exclusive serialization and there is defined default settings i have to do something like that:

```
var defs = JsonConvert.DefaultSettings;
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = null;
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject, settings);
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = defs;
```

**Question**: Is it a bug or i just do not understand something?
if its not a bug, can someone explain me this behavior?

Suddenly i can not prepare fiddle at the moment because of broken nuget packages at https://dotnetfiddle.net

but here is an example of this case:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

public class Program
{
    public enum TestEnum {
        Zero,
        One,
        Two
    }

    public class Something
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public TestEnum Num {get; set;}
    }

    public void Main()
    {
        var test = new Something {
            Name = "foo",
            Num = TestEnum.One
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        // {"Name":"foo","Num":1}

        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = (() =>
            {
            var JsonSetting = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            };
            JsonSetting.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter()
            {
                CamelCaseText = true
            });

            return JsonSetting;
        });     


        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        //{"name":"foo","num":"one"}


        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        //this will result in: {"name":"foo","num":"one"}
        //but i expect this:  {"Name":"foo","Num":1}

    }
}
```

Comment: suddenly in my apps and in the fiddle its not. https://yadi.sk/i/pEEowFruVgXOqA

Comment: The same exact behavior seems to happen on JsonConvert.DeserializeObject as well

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiate a new `JsonSerializerSettings` instance, its `ContractResolver` property is `null`. Then in `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`, a `JsonSerializer` is instantiated and configured with the passed settings.

Relevant code:

```
if (settings.ContractResolver != null)
    serializer.ContractResolver = settings.ContractResolver;
```

The `JsonSerializer`'s constructor initializes its `ContractResolver` to `DefaultContractResolver.Instance`. So if you don't specify a contract resolver in the settings you pass, it'll resolve to the default.

Comment: you are right and defining ContractResolver helps but I also found out that default Converters added to passed settings too if `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` is used, so i ended with own serializer :-/